# How to get pageID from block in view.php at Concrete5 CMS

Tags: php, concrete5

I want transfer some data from page attributes as GET Request data. URL for request I create in block's view.php. How I can get cID of current page in view.php ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$currentPageCID = Page::getCurrentPage()->getCollectionID();`

Comment: Damn, it's so obvious! I tried to get the ID from block's controller. Big Thanks!